# How can I initialize an array of structs containing enum arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, enums, initialization

I tried to translate a Pascal program into a Swift program containing a nested data structure. I was unable to initialize the array, please give advice how I should have written this example.

```
enum  KW: Int {case XXXX=0,YYYY,ZZZZ}
let numCards = 49
typealias Card = [KW]

struct KSet {
    var k1: Card
    var k2: Card
}

var cards: [KSet] = []

func rotate(k:Card) -> Card {
    return([k[2],k[0],k[3],k[1]])
}

func initOne(k: Card) {

     cards.append(k1:k,k2:rotate(k))   // <– does not compile
}

initOne([.XXXX, .YYYY, .ZZZZ, .XXXX])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify

```
cards.append(k1:k,k2:rotate(k))
```

To read

```
cards.append(KSet(k1:k,k2:rotate(k)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert label `k` like this

`cards.append(KSet(k1:k,k2:rotate(k: k)))`

`initOne(k: [.XXXX, .YYYY, .ZZZZ, .XXXX])`

Or if you want to omit it,

`func rotate(_ k:Card) -> Card`

`func initOne(_ k: Card)`